# Why is vertical-align applied to an image also applying to sibling text?

Tags: html, css

I set the `vertical-align` on the image only.

So the `vertical-align` on the text should be the default `vertical-align: baseline`.

But why is the text moving to top, middle, bottom?

```html
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:top;">aaa
</div>
<br>
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:middle;">bbb
</div>
<br>
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:bottom;">bbb
</div>
```

[The demo on code pen](http://codepen.io/Cabage/pen/NAZBPZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break down your code:

```
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:top;">aaa
</div>

<br>

<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:middle;">bbb
</div>

<br>

<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:bottom;">bbb
</div>
```

If you check developer tools, you'll find that the `vertical-align` property is working as instructed for each `img` element.

But what's the computed `vertical-align` value for the anonymous inline box wrapping the text?

It's actually `baseline`. Anonymous boxes inherit parent properties, and when properties are not inheritable, they use initial values ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)). In either case, it's `baseline` here, and the image's `vertical-align` is not being applied.

So when you see the text apparently aligned by the image's `vertical-align` setting (`top`, `middle` or `bottom`), yet the text is actually computing to `baseline`, it comes off as strange and confusing.

**What's actually happening is that the `vertical-align` setting on the image is moving the baseline of the line box.**

Because the image already occupies the full height of the container, `vertical-align` can't move it. There's no extra space.

In order to complete the task, which is to vertically align the element relative to the line box's baseline, the baseline has to move.

To illustrate this behavior, give the line box additional height. Then the baseline will not be forced to move and the text will align as expected.

```css
div { line-height: 185px;}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:top;">aaa
</div>

<br>

<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:middle;">bbb
</div>

<br>

<div style="background-color:#e5edff;">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:bottom;">bbb
</div>
```

More details: [**10.8 Line height calculations: the `line-height` and `vertical-align` properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height)

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the `img` is the largest item in the block. The `img` is, in fact, doing what you are expecting. However, because the block is the same size as the `img`, it looks like the text is moving in relation to the `img`.

Take a look at the fiddle below. This shows what happens when the `img`is no longer the largest item in the block, simply by wrapping the text in its own `div` with an explicit height:

https://jsfiddle.net/csazuk0u/

Answer (score -1):

It's definitely confusing, but consistent with the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp):

> `top`: The top of the element is aligned with the top of the tallest
>   element on the line
>
> `bottom`: The bottom of the element is aligned with the lowest element
>   on the line

Since it seems that the text is the tallest and lowest "element on the line", the image is aligning itself with the top and bottom of the text respectively. The parent div expands to fit the image, so it appears that it's the text moving around instead of the image.

This may be clearer to see by setting the parent height to taller than the image:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:top;">aaa</div>
<br>
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:middle;">bbb</div>
<br>
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:bottom;">ccc</div>
```

We notice that the image is aligning itself relative to the text, not relative to the parent.

Answer (score -1):

When you set a vertical alignment on an image, it's the orientation relative to the text (or other inline element) block. I think your code "works as designed".

Here is an example which has a lot of text and might better illustrate my point.

```
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:top;">aaaLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
  exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto
  odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem
  insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam
  littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.

</div>
<br>
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:middle;">bbLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan
  et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent
  claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est
  notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum. b

</div>
<br>
<div style="background-color:#e5edff;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="vertical-align:bottom;">bbbLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan
  et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent
  claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est
  notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.

</div>
```

[my CodePen example](http://codepen.io/asonnenshine/pen/LkrJxX)

Maybe you have a question about how to achieve a specific layout with images and text that we can help with?